# how to hide image left part of image when using overflow hidden

Tags: css, html

I am new to CSS programming . Using `overflow:hidden` for hiding image greater than DIV area. Perhaps I want hidden part of image should be in the left part, but currently its taking right part. My code follows as below.

Html code:

```
<div class="a1">
<img src="img/image4.jpg">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
 .a1{height:200px;width:100px; overflow:hidden;}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this (notice the `direction: rtl;`):

```css
.a1 {
  height:200px;
  width:100px;
  overflow:hidden;
  direction: rtl;
}
```

```html
<div class="a1">
  <img src="http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/sprites.png?v=3c6263c3453b">
</div>
```

Comment: How did I not know about `direction: rtl`?  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```css
.a1 {
  height:200px;
  width:100px;
  overflow:hidden;
  background:#ff0;
}
```

```html
<div class="a1">
<img src="http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/sprites.png?v=3c6263c3453b">
</div>
```

Seems to work fine for me.  I added the yellow background to show where the DIV is at and linked to an SO sprite.

If you're getting a different effect, then it's quite likely the CSS on your page elsewhere which is cascading and causing the conflict.

Side note: Writing a stylesheet in CSS is not really called "programming". :)

Click Run code snippet to see this in action.

Or, for the converse:

```css
.a1 {
  height:200px;
  width:100px;
  overflow:hidden;
  background:#ff0;
}
```

```html
<div class="a1">
<img src="http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/sprites.png?v=3c6263c3453b" align="right">
</div>
```

Comment: I don't think this is what the OP want. This is exactly what happens to the OP. What OP need is showing the right part of the `image` and hide the overflowing left part of the image

Comment: @Kyojimaru Oh, thanks. Reading it, that's not what I took away from it, clearly.  One must love language differences, eh?

Answer (score 1):

```css
.a1 {
  height:200px;
  width:100px;
  overflow:hidden;
  direction: rtl;
}
```

```html
<div class="a1">
  <img src="https://www.google.com.pk/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png">
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

use `float:right` for image element

```
<div style="width:200px; height:200px; overflow:hidden">

    <img style="float:right" src="url" />

</div>
```